# AES CBC обрезает строку, которая больше 16 символов

Tags: java, криптография, aes

AES CBC обрезает строку, которая больше 16 символов. При следующем запуске выводит  `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.`

UPD: Вот проблемный код:

```
public static byte[][] encrypt(String txt, String txt2, String txt3){
try {
            SecretKey mysecretKey = new SecretKeySpec("qwertyuiopasdfgh".getBytes(), "AES");
            byte[] plainText1 = txt.getBytes();
            byte[] plainText2 = txt2.getBytes();
            byte[] plainText3 = txt3.getBytes();
            byte[][] plain_bytes = new byte[][] { plainText1, plainText2, plainText3 };
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("4283810222669651".getBytes());
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mysecretKey, iv);
            cipher.update(plainText1);
            byte[] cipherText1 = cipher.doFinal();
            cipher.update(plainText2);
            byte[] cipherText2 = cipher.doFinal();
            cipher.update(plainText3);
            byte[] cipherText3 = cipher.doFinal();
            byte[][] encrypted_bytes = new byte[][] { cipherText1, cipherText2, cipherText3 };
            String str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted_bytes[0]);
            encryptedUrl = str;
            System.out.println(encryptedUrl);
            return encrypted_bytes;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return null;
    
}
    }
```

Comment: Без исходников здесь не разобраться. Приложите свои исходники

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, @Эникейщик, здесь все хитрее.

ТС пытается использовать мультипартное кодирование через `cipher.update()/doFinal()` и делает это неправильно.

Надо просто к каждому своему куску применять `doFinal()` примерно так:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mysecretKey, iv);
cipherText1=cipher.doFinal(plainText1);
```

Answer (score 0):

AES шифрует блоками по 128 бит (т.е. эти ваши 16 байт). Ошибка говорит вам, что последний блок меньше этого размера и его нужно чем-то заполнить, чтобы достичь 128 бит.